# excel macro spacing string and format

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in an excel macro.  All I need to do is put a space between my string and the date string that comes out of the format however,  I get only the string part if I remove the string I get only the date obviously.

```
filenamestring = "CMC_Rates " & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")
```

any ideas?

Here's more code

```
Dim filenamestring As String
Dim location As String
Dim passparam As String


location = Year(DateTime.Now) & "/" & Month(DateTime.Now)


filenamestring = "CMC_Rates " & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd ") & Format(Range("EffTime").Value, "hhmm AMPM") & ".pdf"




passparam = location & "/" & filenamestring

Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c \\atlanta2-0\MKTG\Rates\SaveFile.bat " & filenamestring, vbNormalFocus)
```

SaveFile.bat has this in it

```
pscp -batch -pw password filename.xlsx admin@172.17.1.5:/Path/%1
```

When it opens the bat it says the paramater is just CMC_Rates, however if I take out the space and put it all together it works.

Comment: Perhaps "CMC_Rates" & chr(32) & Format(Now),"yyyymmdd") ?

Comment: same result as using space.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. When I run the code as is, I get what looks like string+space+date.  Ditto when I wrap the format function in Cstr( ).

Comment: Works in my Excel 2003 without any change. Are you sure you only get the string part, not that the date part is "blocked"/covered by next non-empty sibling cell?

Comment: I guess your bat file can't accept file names with spaces in - try putting the whole lot in double quotes too like `Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c \\atlanta2-0\MKTG\Rates\SaveFile.bat " & """" & filenamestring & """", vbNormalFocus)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with this line: (split for readability)

```
Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") _
  & " /c \\atlanta2-0\MKTG\Rates\SaveFile.bat " _
  & filenamestring, vbNormalFocus)
```

when Excel calls your batch file, the *COMSPEC* interpreter treats the filename as more than one argument, as spaces are used as separators. To indicate the filename is one argument, and not many, it needs to be enclosed in quotes **"**

This will change the line to this:

```
Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") _
  & " /c \\atlanta2-0\MKTG\Rates\SaveFile.bat " _
  & chr(34) & filenamestring & chr(34), vbNormalFocus)
```